# Solving for rate to make NPV zero Python

Tags: python, numpy

My solution so far (which does not work and gets stuck) which uses NPV formula for monthly cashflow and attempts to find the discount rate to make it zero:

```
def goal_seek(target,cashflows,_threshold):
    threshold = _threshold
    lower = -10000
    upper = 10000
    solve = (lower + upper)/2
    while abs(threshold) >= _threshold:
        print(f'Threshold is: {threshold}')
        print(f'range is: {lower}  ----  {solve}   ----   {upper}')
        if threshold < 0:
            upper = solve
            solve = (lower + upper)/2
        elif threshold > 0:
            lower = solve
            solve = (lower + upper)/2        
        threshold = target - numpy.npv(((numpy.sign(solve) * (numpy.abs(solve)+1) ** (1 / 12))-1),cashflows)

    print(f'Final result: Threshold: {threshold}....Solved input: {solve}')

            
        return solve

goal_seek(0,[-1,0,0,0,.5],.0001)
```

Implementing the above example results in this binary search algorithm getting stuck on below

Threshold is: 0.9767928293785059
range is: 10000.0  ----  10000.0   ----   10000

Is there an easy scipy module to solve for a single variable non-linear equation such as NPV?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want.

`np.npv()`
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.npv.html
`np.irr()`
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.irr.html